# How to open an Access database that has an error on AutoExec?

Tags: ms-access, vba, autoexec

I created an AutoExec macro on Access 2007 and wanted to try a new function I created on VBA, but the function throws an error and everytime I open the database I get an error and the database closes, so I can't edit the code or the AutoExec macro because the application closes right after ending the AutoExec.

Any idea how can I open the database without having to run the AutoExec?

Comment: I really need to enter the database because I didn't create a backup, my mistake :S

Comment: We like errors, they tell us their secrets. Mind to share?

Comment: It only says "Found an error, and the application will be closed" or something like that, I'm using Access in spanish. The title of the error prompt just says "Microsoft Office Access"

Comment: this isn't a duplicate of the linked question, this one is for opening the database interactively, the linked question is for opening it programatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opening the DB by holding down the SHIFT key until the DB is loaded. This will disable all macros before running. This way you can open the DB, correct the error and then try it again.

Comment: Thanks, read that in other page and it worked. Thanks everybody!

Comment: What other page? Anyway, you can still mark the one above if it also helped. It might help someone searching for a similar question. Thanks.

Comment: This page: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/bypass-startup-options-when-you-open-a-database-HA010226996.aspx

Comment: Okay ! Glad you have it sorted.

Comment: Thanks! If I had not found it there, you would have helped me!

Comment: Ha Ha ! Well one way or the other eh? The bottom line is you have it working. Good luck ! :)